# Using Ansible to orchestrate (delegate_to)

Tags: ansible, chef-infra

Let me mention first that I am new to ansible. so my approach could be completely wrong here.

I am trying to use ansible to orchestrate some steps for me. I'm trying to write a playbook that will run modify the chef run_list from my localhost using knife. I believe I am supposed to use delgate_to.

Now if i run:
    ansible-playbook site.yml --limit=host1,host2,host3

My task looks like this at the moment, however its not functional. i have a node variable but what i really want is all the nodes that are apart of the --limit option above and i want to iterate over it. how am I supposed to get this accomplished?

```
- name: Adding monitoring chef cookbooks to node's run list
  shell: knife node run_list add {{ item }} {{ run_list }}
  with_items: "{{ node }}"
  delegate_to: localhost
```

Thanks.

Comment: It would probably be easier to make a small custom module using PyChef or a similar Python API binding.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
- name: Test
  hosts: all
  connection: local
  tasks:
     - shell: knife node run_list add {{ inventory_hostname }} {{ run_list }}
       delegate_to: localhost
```

Comment: Thank you. You are awesome!

Comment: Wouldn't the "{{node}}" variable be out of scope since this is a new play?